# android adapter getView method do not work

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

working on  android application and i have a listview which need adapter ... my problem when i send context an arraylist parameters  to adapter ... the getView method do not work ,

here is where i called the adapter in main activity where arraylist is full

```
adapter = new ArticlesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arraylist);
        content.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and here full adapter code

```
public class ArticlesAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private ArrayList<ArticlesBean> arr;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    public ArticlesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ArticlesBean> arraylist){
        this.arr = arraylist;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);



    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arr.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arr.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.e("get view","in get view");

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customfavlist, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();


            holder.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ltitle);
            holder.ldesc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ldesc);
            v.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

        }

        holder.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ltitle);
        holder.ldesc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ldesc);

        holder.title.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        holder.title.setText(arr.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.ldesc.setText(arr.get(position).getBody().substring(0, 45).replace("\n", " "));




        return v;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        private TextView title;
        private TextView ldesc;
    }

    public void refresh(ArrayList<ArticlesBean> items) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        arr.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        // notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: show how u r intializing the adapter and the adapters constructor

Comment: make sure you are overriding `getCount()` method of Adapter by returning `arr.size()`

Comment: what do you mean with "the getView method do not work"?

Comment: my adapter working fine and it is have values but getView do not called

Comment: @OdaiKarajah show how u r intializing the adapter and the adapters constructor

Comment: Can you please share the whole code where the adapter is called?

Comment: thanks to your in interest .... i willedit my question

Comment: 1. make sure ur arraylist has some elements 2. make sure the listview is visible and inside the screen layouts

Comment: make sure size is not zero

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

to

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

and

```
adapter = new ArticlesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arraylist);
```

to

```
adapter = new ArticlesAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
```